# MFC: MIME type "text/css" not recognized by IInternetProtocolSink

Tags: internet-explorer, mfc, webbrowser-control, mime, ole

I have a webbrowser control with a pluggable protocol based on the IInternetProtocol interface. When loading HTML sites, everything is fine. But when loading an external CSS stylesheet, the MIME type "text/css" reported to **BINDSTATUS_MIMETYPEAVAILABLE** and **BINDSTATUS_VERIFIEDMIMETYPEAVAILABLE** is ignored.

- if I set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION in the registry to 8888 (IE8), the external CSS is rendered correctly (in folder 'Registry')
- if I set FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION in the registry to 11001 (IE11) or anything except IE 8 compatibility modes, the external CSS is ignored (in folder 'Registry')
- if the HTML site contains the meta tag IE=edge, the external CSS is ignored, since this forces the webbrowser control to IE11 mode
- if I switch off the pluggable protocol, external CSS is rendered, independent of the value set for FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
- if I switch off the pluggable protocol and deliver the CSS stylesheet with a mismatching wrong MIME type from the demo server (in folder 'Server') , the behaviour of the pluggable protocol can be reproduced both in IE and in the webbrowser control
- reporting the headers to the IHttpNegotiate interface has no effect
- any other feature controls set with CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled have no effect

**My conclusions so far**:

- IE8 and the webbrowser control in IE8 mode completely ignores MIME types and finds it out by MIME sniffing
- IE9 and later fail, if the wrong MIME type is delivered
- the webbrowser in IE9+ mode control ignores the MIME type "text/css" as any other MIME types set for CSS stylesheets

**My questions**:

- Did anyone encounter a similar problem with pluggable protocols? If yes, how did you solve this?
- How do I properly load and report CSS stylesheets to the IInternetProtocolSink?

Here you can download the sample project, which demonstrates the behaviour:
https://github.com/elsamuko/SimpleBrowser

Here are screenshots of the different behaviours:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VTw0.jpg

Links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/157329/Http-Monitor-for-Webbrowser-Control
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12865/An-Asynchronous-Pluggable-Protocol-Handler-for-dat

Comment: Try this and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21654398/1768303

Comment: See the last point: "any other feature controls set with CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled have no effect"

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem working on a C# project the same day this question was posted.

The problem was solved by reporting a BINDSTATUS_CACHEFILENAMEAVAILABLE to the sink.
Of course this will only works if you have a local copy of the file available.
The code below is in C# but it gives a general idea of how this works.

It will even work without the BINDSTATUS_MIMETYPEAVAILABLE but this might cause other problems. So this is not reccomended.

Hope this helps ...

```
sink.ReportProgress(UrlMon.BINDSTATUS.BINDSTATUS_MIMETYPEAVAILABLE, mimetype);
sink.ReportProgress(UrlMon.BINDSTATUS.BINDSTATUS_CACHEFILENAMEAVAILABLE, localfilename);
sink.ReportData(UrlMon.BSCF.BSCF_DATAFULLYAVAILABLE, 0, 0);
sink.ReportResult(0, 200, null);
```

An addition:

You might have no other option than to write to the disc when implementing the async. pluggable protocol. Together with the request comes a lot of extra flags. One of these flags is the BINDF.BINDF_NEEDFILE flags (the first parameter of the IInternetBindInfo::GetBindInfo method). This flags forces you to return a file.

This might even be the cause of the original problem. For some reason (only known to Microsoft) Internet Explorer forces a css file to exists on disc by adding the BINDF_NEEDFILE. Search the internet for BINDF_NEEDFILE and you will get lots of explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I cannot write the files to disc though, so this won't work for me. Do you know, if I can pass a pointer to the data instead of a filename?

Comment: You might have no other option than to write to the disc when implementing the async. pluggable protocol. Together with the request comes a lot of extra flags. One of these flags is the BINDF.BINDF_NEEDFILE flags (the first parameter of the IInternetBindInfo::GetBindInfo method). This flags forces you to return a file.

Comment: The requests for CSS files have the following flags set:  
ASYNCHRONOUS ASYNCSTORAGE PULLDATA NO_UI SILENTOPERATION DIRECT_READ FROMURLMON  

There is no BINDF_NEEDFILE for these requests.