# AccessViolationException from WebBrowser control with custom IDownloadManager

Tags: c#, com, webbrowser-control

My .NET application hosts a WebBrowser control, and I've attached a custom download manager.  Everything seems to work fine except for requests with the following two HTTP headers:

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=blahblahblah
```

Change or omit the content type header, and everything works fine; it's just application/octet-stream that has the problem.  Remove the content disposition header and the download manager isn't used.

Interestingly, this problem only happens on 32 bit machines (I've tested XP and Win 7 32 bit.  Win 7/8 64 bit do not crash).

What's so special about `application/octet-stream`?

In case it helps, here's a ton of code that registers the custom download manager. It was inspired by this question and answer: [Windows Forms Webbrowswer control with IDownloadManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362922/windows-forms-webbrowswer-control-with-idownloadmanager)

In my class that derives from `WebBrowser`:

```
protected override WebBrowserSiteBase CreateWebBrowserSiteBase()
{
    var site = new DownloadWebBrowserSite(this);
    return site;
}
```

In `DownloadWebBrowserSite`:

```
    DownloadManager _manager = new DownloadManager();

    public int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, out IntPtr ppvObject)
    {
        if (guidService.CompareTo(ComInteropConstants.IID_IDownloadManager) == 0 && riid.CompareTo(ComInteropConstants.IID_IDownloadManager) == 0)
        {
            IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(_manager);
            return Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref riid, out ppvObject);
        }
        ppvObject = IntPtr.Zero;
        return ComInteropConstants.E_NOINTERFACE;
    }
```

`DownloadManager` is my custom download manager.  Its implementation of `Download` is below.

```
public int Download(IMoniker pmk, IBindCtx pbc, uint dwBindVerb, int grfBINDF, IntPtr pBindInfo, string pszHeaders, string pszRedir, uint uiCP)
{
    return ComInteropConstants.S_OK;
}
```

It implements `IDownloadManager`, declared below.

```
[ComVisible(false), ComImport]
[Guid("988934A4-064B-11D3-BB80-00104B35E7F9")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IDownloadManager
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int Download(
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IMoniker pmk,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] IBindCtx pbc,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint dwBindVerb,
        [In] int grfBINDF,
        [In] IntPtr pBindInfo,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszHeaders,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszRedir,
        [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint uiCP);
}
```

To reproduce the crash, I don't need to actually do anything inside that method.

Comment: Have you used WinDBG to look at where the AV is occurring specifically? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2014/01/15/debugging-internet-explorer-with-windbg.aspx

Comment: In terms of "What's so special about application/octet-stream"-- it's an ambiguous type (which triggers sniffing) and it's also likely that you have one or more MIME Filters registered for that type. See the subkey of HKCR\Protocols\.

Comment: @JeffMeadows, it might help if you show the managed declaration of `IDownloadManager`. On a side note, both your code and the original answer do not release `punk` after `Marshal.QueryInterface`. Release it with `Marshall.Release`.

Comment: @Noseratio When is the right time to call `Marshal.Release`?  I'll edit to show `IDownloadManager`'s declaration. @EricLaw, the only MIME filter registered for that type is mscorie - Cor MIME Fltr.  I'll give WinDBG a look to see if that can help.  Thanks!

Comment: Right after `QueryInterface`, when you no longer need `punk`. Use `try/finally` for that.

Comment: FWIW, the Cor MIME Filter (used for running .NET user controls in IE) has been deprecated since 2009 or so and you might try temporarily removing it to see if there's any impact.

Comment: @EricLaw I used WinDbg to look at the exception.  It's coming from `ieframe!CDocObjectHost::CDOHBindStatusCallback::_ProcessCLASSIDBindStatus+10d`  Interestingly, if the extension specified in the the `Content-Disposition` header has an associated registry entry in HKCR\<extension>, no crash!

Comment: Very strange; might be worth using gFlags to set pageheap, etc, to see if maybe something in the marshalling is corrupting the heap. Do you get a crash if you compile your AnyCPU app as "x86" and run it on the 64bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't fully understand why my application was crashing, nor do I fully understand why the following code fixed it, but here's what ended up preventing the crash:

```
[DllImport("urlmon.dll"), PreserveSig]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Error)]
static extern int CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(int FeatureEntry, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]uint dwFlags, bool fEnable);

CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(ComInteropConstants.FEATURE_MIME_HANDLING, (uint)ComInteropConstants.SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(ComInteropConstants.FEATURE_MIME_SNIFFING, (uint)ComInteropConstants.SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, true);
```

So it looks like without these features turned on (MIME handling and MIME sniffing), bad HTTP responses (content type application/octet-stream with text content) cause problems.

Comment: I know this is pretty rude, but I don't suppose you're willing to share your full implementation of IDownloadManager? I'm trying to create a customised download manager.

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't got much of a full implementation. I just wanted to allow a user to download a file via WebBrowser control. What I did was actually pop open the user's default web browser to handle the downloading.